Proving absolute convergence of improper integrals implies convergence
I am trying to prove the following:

Let $f$ be integrable on $[a,x]$ for every $a\le x<\star$ where either $\star=\infty$ or $f$ is unbounded in a left neighbourhood of $\star$. Then $$\int_{a}^{\star}{|f|}\text{ converges}\implies \int_{a}^{\star}f\text{ converges}$$

I am aware that $$\left|\int_a ^xf \right|\le \int_a ^x |f|\le\int_a^\star |f|$$ which shows that $\left|\int_a ^xf \right|$ is bounded, but I can't rule out infinite oscillation as $x\to \star^-$. I was also able to prove the following

If $\int_a^\star |f|$ converges, then for every $\varepsilon>0$, there exists an $x_0\in[a,\star)$ s.t. $$x_1,x_2\in(x_0,\star) \implies\left|\int_{x_1}^{x_2}f\right|< \varepsilon$$

which I think might be useful in showing that infinite oscillation is indeed not possible, but I am unable to proceed. I am not looking for a complete solution; only helpful hints to direct me to the right direction.

You're almost done with the result $x_1,x_2\in (x_0,\star)\implies \left|\int_{x_1}^{x_2} f\right|<\varepsilon$ you proved; see RRL's answer. Here are hints/steps towards an alternate approach:
Define the functions $f^+:[a,\star)\to\mathbb R$ and $f^-:[a,\star)\to\mathbb R$ by
$$f^+(x) = \begin{cases}f(x) &\text{if }f(x)\geq 0\\0 &\text{if }f(x)<0\end{cases}$$
$$f^-(x) = \begin{cases}f(x) &\text{if }f(x)\leq 0\\0 &\text{if }f(x)>0\end{cases}$$
These are known as the positive and negative parts of $f$, respectively. Both $f^+$ and $f^-$ are integrable on $[a,x]$ for every $x\in (a,\star)$; the proof is hidden in the spoiler in case you want to figure this out yourself.

 The definitions of $f^+$ and $f^-$ immediately yield the identities $f=f^++f^-$ and $|f|=f^+-f^-$. Taking this as a linear system in $f^+$ and $f^-$, we can then solve for each to get
 $$f^+=\frac{f+|f|}{2}\text{ and }f^-=\frac{f-|f|}{2}$$
 The integrability of $f^+$ and $f^-$ follow from $|f|$ being integrable.

Once you've proven the integrability of $f^+$ and $f^-$, consider the integrals $I^+(t):=\int_a^t f^+(x)dx$ and $I^-(t):=\int_a^t f^-(x)dx$, both defined on $(a,\star)$. It can be proven that $\lim_{t\to \star}I^+(t)$ and $\lim_{t\to\star}I^-(t)$ both exist; for hints, see the next spoiler.

 Notice that $I^+$ is monotone increasing because $f^+$ is non-negative. Similarly, $I^-$ is monotone decreasing. Using the identity $|f|=f^+-f^-$, deduce that $I^+$ is bounded above and $I^-$ is bounded below. The existence of the limits $\lim_{t\to\star}I^+(t)$ and $\lim_{t\to\star}I^-(t)$ will follow from the monotone convergence theorem.

To wrap things up, notice that
$$\int_a^t f(x)dx=I^+(t)+I^-(t)$$
so
$$\lim_{t\to \star}\int_a^t f(x)dx=\lim_{t\to \star}I^+(t)+\lim_{t\to \star}I^-(t)$$

Thank you. This was a very nice approach and apparently much simpler than what I was trying to attempt, though it doesn't seem like something I'd ever come up with myself.

You are done if you can prove both sides of the following.
Lemma  Suppose $g$ is integrable on $[a,x]$ for all $a \leqslant x < \star$. The improper integral $\int_a^\star g$ converges if and only if for every $\epsilon > 0$ there esists $x_0 \in [a,\star)$ such that for all $x_1,x_2 \in [a,\star)$ w we have
$$\tag{#}x_0 \leqslant x_1 \leqslant x_2 \implies \left| \int_{x_1}^{x_2} g\right|< \epsilon$$
With this Cauchy criterion for improper integrals in hand, your hypothesis that the improper integral of $|f|$ converges allows you to assert that
$$\left| \int_{x_1}^{x_2} f\right| < \int_{x_1}^{x_2}|f| <\epsilon,$$
and then you can conclude that the improper integral of $f$ converges.
Proving the forward implication of the Lemma is straightforward.
For the reverse implication here are some hints. Define the sequence
$$I_n = \begin{cases} \int_a^{a+n} g & \text{if }\star = \infty, \\ \int_a^{b- 1/n} g & \text{ if } \star = b\end{cases} $$
Using the result (#) show that $I_n$ is a Cauchy sequence  and must converge to a real number $I$.  Then apply (#) again to show that the definition of convergence for an improper integral is satisfied.  That is, for every $\epsilon > 0$ there exists a real number $K \in [a,\star)$ such that if $K \leqslant c < \star$ then
$$\left| \int_a^c g  - I\right| < \epsilon$$

Thank you for your answer. Unfortunately, I have not studied infinite sequences yet, so I am unfamiliar with "Cauchy sequences". Is there a way to proceed with the proof without them or should I defer it until I formally study sequences?

@VulgarMechanick: You're welcome.  Usually that is covered first. You  need in the very least to have learned the concept of the limit of a function, as an improper integral is defined as $\int_a^\infty f = \lim_{c \to\infty} I(c) := \lim_{c \to \infty}\int_a^cf$.  To prove that a limit exists there can be several ways to go.  The Cauchy criterion is one powerful approach.  More transparent -- when it is applicable  -- is monotone convergence which is used in the other answer.  That is, if $I(c)$ is bounded above for all $c$ and increases with $c$, then the limit as $c \to \infty$ exists.

I am actually well versed with the $\epsilon-\delta$ limit of a function, but sequences are actually covered at the end in my text, which is why I haven't to them yet. I was not familiar with "Monotone convergence theorem" in the context of sequences but was aware that increasing bounded functions have a limit. In any case, I will make sure to reference this answer once I go over sequences. Many thanks
